# Spring security: save sessions status and get sessions after restart app

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I use spring security, that create sessions if user has authorized. I want to get all active sessions if I restart my app. This means that if the user is authorized and I reloaded my application, the user should not be authorized again, he should continue to work in his session. How can i did this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with _Spring Security_ specifically but is rather about _sessions_ (and the accepted answer, recommending Spring Session, is the best solution). Spring Security simply stores information _inside_ the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store all the session details either in the database or Cache.

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

or

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Refer to the below documentation,

Cache: https://spring.io/projects/spring-session-data-redis

Database: https://spring.io/projects/spring-session-jdbc

Session Properties: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#security-properties